# SonataAdminBundle can't see logout in top right

Tags: symfony

all works fine but i can't see logout icon and + icon in top right
i followed all step in sonata-project officiel site but i don't know what is happen really. in the officiel site i see in demo in the last step logout but in my project i can't 
[image]
i use symfony 2.8.0
this my config.yml

```
    imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }
    - { resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/admin.yml" }
parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }
# app/config/config.yml
sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        # enable the SonataAdminBundle block
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts: [admin]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this behaviour is handled by SonataUserBundle, you must to install this, if you see in the Sonata User introduction you can see that this bundle enable the user profile, and I think that this user icon.

[Sonata User Bundle](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/master/doc/reference/introduction.html)

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple way to accomplish this without the need to add the SonataUserBundle.
You can use a custom made template for **user_block** where you can add the logout link and links to some profile view by doing the following.

**Add this to your *security.yml***

```
security:
  role_hierarchy
    ROLE_ADMIN:      [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN]
```

**Now add this to your *config.yml***

```
## Sonata Configuration
# Sonata Admin
sonata_admin:
  ## ... other config
  templates:
    user_block: AppBundle:Default:user_block.html.twig
```

**Finally add a template file called *user_block.html.twig* in *src/AppBundle/Resources/views/Default/* with your desired links and content** (below an example of the default **user_block** of the SonataUserBundle

```
{#
  This file is part of the Sonata package.
  (c) Thomas Rabaix <thomas.rabaix@sonata-project.org>
  For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
  file that was distributed with this source code.
#}

{% block user_block %}
    {% if app.user %}
        {% set _bg_class          = "bg-light-blue" %}
        {% set _logout_uri        = url('sonata_user_admin_security_logout') %}
    {% set _logout_text       = 'user_block_logout'|trans({}, 'SonataUserBundle') %}
    {% set _profile_uri       = sonata_user.userAdmin.isGranted('EDIT', app.user) ? sonata_user.userAdmin.generateUrl('edit', {id: app.user.id}) : sonata_user.userAdmin.generateUrl('show', {id: app.user.id}) %}
    {% set _profile_text      = 'user_block_profile'|trans({}, 'SonataUserBundle') %}
    {% set _user_image        = sonata_user.defaultAvatar ? asset(sonata_user.defaultAvatar) : null %}
    {# Customize this with your profile picture implementation, see below for example #}
    {#{% set _user_image  = app.user.profilePicture|default(asset(sonata_user.defaultAvatar)) %}#}

    {% if is_granted('ROLE_PREVIOUS_ADMIN') and sonata_user.impersonating %}
        {% set _bg_class    = "bg-light-green" %}
        {% set _logout_uri  = url(sonata_user.impersonating.route, sonata_user.impersonating.parameters| merge({'_switch_user': '_exit'})) %}
        {% set _logout_text = 'switch_user_exit'|trans({}, 'SonataUserBundle') %}
    {% endif %}

    <li class="user-header {{ _bg_class }}">
        {% if _user_image %}
            <img src="{{ _user_image }}" class="img-circle" alt="Avatar"/>
        {% endif %}
        <p>{{ app.user }}</p>
    </li>

    <li class="user-body">
    </li>

    <li class="user-footer">
        <div class="pull-left">
            <a href="{{ _profile_uri }}" class="btn btn-default btn-flat"><i
                        class="fa fa-user"></i> {{ _profile_text }}</a>
        </div>

        <div class="pull-right">
            <a href="{{ _logout_uri }}" class="btn btn-default btn-flat"><i
                        class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> {{ _logout_text }}</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

But in my honest opinion it is best to implement the SonataUserBundle and I use it together with the FOSUserBundle and FOSOauthServerBundle.